# How to get jsdoc generation for parms of class methods that use arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, documentation, jsdoc

I'm a student who's capstone project/work intergrated learning is about to end. I'm working on producing technical documentation to hand off to the next team that will continue on with this work, but I've hit a snag.

My class methods that use arrow functions aren't generating params documentation when I create documentation using the `jsdoc` tool.

i.e.:
[image: Image of the documentation in source code.]
becomes
[image: Image of the resulting jsdoc output.]

The documentation works as intended in visual studio code/intellisense:
[image: Image of the documentation correctly working in visual studio code for the param]

I've been googling around to try and figure out what the problem was, but I failed to find anything.

I mean, my research yielded:

- Outdated way to make vscode play nice with arrow function
  syntax: (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36283) (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22264) ((This one is the actual issue where the support was added) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14134)
- Outdated info on the jsdoc support for this feature:
  https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1310
- etc., etc., again, nothing useful.

Of note is that I'm using the `jsdoc-export-default-interop` plugin so that jsdoc will actually generate things for `export default [CLASS OR FUNCTION]`.

Comment: That's not a class method, it's a property that *happens* to be a method. Try defining it as `onPressItem(id) {...}`. See ["class method arrow"](https://www.google.com/search?q=class+method+arrow).

Comment: @laggingreflex, oh yeah. It's a property that stores an anonymous function/method. We were having issues when we defined our methods as class methods, because we needed to pass the method as a first-class-function object thingy to other react components. I can't remember exactly what the problem was, either a crash or the method was immediately invoked instead of composed.

I'm looking to generate params documentation for the anonymous function.

Answer (score 4):

## I've found a solution that fits my requirements

However, while it is good enough for my purposes, I'm not entirely sure it's acurate and would be happy to hear critisims, other people's viewpoints and solutions. I'll explain the concerns I have at the end.

### The problem: It looks like jsdoc cannot automatically detect if a member assignment is a function when parsing.

I have no idea why VSCode is able to detect it automatically, but it appears the JSDoc tool cannot. Here it is stated in the official documentation
[image: Image of documentation]
Link to documentation: (https://jsdoc.app/tags-function.html)

### The solution: Document the member with the `@function` tag (or an alias like `@method`).

By documenting the class member with the `@function` tag like so:
[image: Image of the code documented with the @function tag]

I am able to get the arrow function to generate as a class method, and get params documentation:
[image: Image of the generated documentation]

### My concerns

Well the biggest concern/annoyance is now I need to go through all the source code and add a bunch of `@function` tags. Ah whelp.

Other concerns are that I may have misunderstood the problem/I'm not quite sure if this is best practice.

And I'm not too certain if this documentation is accurate in terms of if there is actually a tangible difference between a class member arrow function and a class method that I need to capture in the API documentation.

Anyway, I think this will be what I go with, but I'll be monitoring this answer to read any input/feedback :)